# Stochastic weight binarization

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, stochastic

I am reading [BinaryConnect](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.00363.pdf) paper of Bengio. I understand the whole idea and how to do deterministic binarization. However, I did not understand how the stochastic binarization works (how can we implement that) and what is the difference between stochastic binarization and deterministic binarization. Any explanation ?

Answer (score 0):

The major difference between deterministic and stochastic binarization is the binarization method. In deterministic binarization, the result of binarization is 1 when the input value is bigger than a certain threshold (e.g., 0), and 0 otherwise. However, in stochastic binarization, the result could be 1 with probability related to the input value. You can find more details in [Accelerating Neural Networks with Binary Arithmetic](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/artificial-intelligence/posts/accelerating-neural-networks-binary-arithmetic.html)
.